Which community is being referred to?
After the successful detonation of the Trinity test, Robert Oppenheimer and
Edward Teller watched as two prototypes of atomic bombs were being
transported for deployment against Japan:

Robert: The fact that we built this bomb does not give us any more...
any more right or responsibility to decide how it's used than anyone
else.
Edward: But we're the only people who know about it.
Edward: I've told Stimson the various opinions of the community.

Which community is being referred to?

This section of the movie appears to relate to a petition that was being circulated within the Manhattan Project camp. Oppenheimer became aware of it, but refused to sign personally and went on to inform Groves about it.
The petition represented a significant portion of the scientific community at Los Alamos (e.g. those that were officially aware of the bomb's existence and its potential purpose and power).

TWO WEEKS after Oppenheimer wrote his June 16 memo summarizing the
views of the science panel, Edward Teller came to him with a copy of a
petition that was circulating throughout the Manhattan Project’s
facilities. Drafted by Leo Szilard, the petition urged President
Truman not to use atomic weapons on Japan without a public statement
of the terms of surrender: “. . . the United States shall not resort
to the use of atomic bombs in this war unless the terms which will be
imposed upon Japan have been made public in detail and Japan knowing
these terms has refused to surrender. . . .” Over the next few weeks,
Szilard’s petition garnered the signatures of 155 Manhattan Project
scientists. A counter-petition mustered only two signatures. In a
separate July 12, 1945, Army poll of 150 scientists in the project,
seventy-two percent favored a demonstration of the bomb’s power as
against its military use without prior warning. Even so, Oppenheimer
expressed real anger when Teller showed him Szilard’s petition.
According to Teller, Oppie began disparaging Szilard and his cohorts:
“What do they know about Japanese psychology? How can they judge the
way to end the war?” These were judgments better left in the hands of
men like Stimson and General Marshall. “Our conversation was brief,”
Teller wrote in his memoirs. “His talking so harshly about my close
friends and his impatience and vehemence greatly distressed me. But I
readily accepted his decision. . . .”
Oppie informed Groves of the Szilard petition—and did so in a disparaging tone: “The enclosed note [from Szilard to Creutz] is a further incident in the developments which I know you have watched with interest.” Groves’ aide, Colonel Nichols, called Groves that same day and in the course of their discussion of the Szilard petition, “Nichols asked why not get rid of the lion [Szilard] and general stated can’t do that at this time.” Groves understood that firing or arresting Szilard would inspire a revolt among the other scientists. But with Oppenheimer equally annoyed by Szilard’s actions, Groves felt confident that the problem could be safely contained until the bomb was ready.
American Prometheus: The Triumph and Tragedy of J. Robert Oppenheimer

